# Sabre ticketing confirmation via Web services

Tags: sabre

While trying to issue tickets for PNR with stored negotiated fare we get following message in return:

```
<AirTicketRS xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:stl="http://services.sabre.com/STL/v01" Version="2.2.0">
<stl:ApplicationResults status="NotProcessed">
<stl:Error type="BusinessLogic" timeStamp="2017-01-16T23:50:16-06:00">
<stl:SystemSpecificResults>
<stl:HostCommand LNIATA="E2A2BC">W¥PQ1¥ETR¥FCA¥ASU¥DOB</stl:HostCommand>
<stl:Message>UNABLE TO TICKET STORED FARE - NEGOTIATED FARE STORED</stl:Message>
<stl:Message>CONTINUE TO TICKET? ENTER Y OR N<.></stl:Message>
<stl:ShortText>ERR.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE</stl:ShortText>
</stl:SystemSpecificResults>
</stl:Error>
</stl:ApplicationResults>
</AirTicketRS>
```

Use `SabreCommandLLSRQ` with `Y` does not help - Sabre insists on `Y` or `N`.

Any ideas on how can we send a confirmation `Y` back for process to go on?

Thanks,
McSeem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original problem was with "[Allow Ticket CAT 35 IT/BT PQ Fare](https://formatfinder.sabre.com/Content/TravelJournalRecordTJR/TJRTicketing/TJRTicketFromStoredFare.aspx?ItemID=bc697c2d4b8348c18ddf34940088d8d2)" PCC setting.
Turning this ON allows autoconfirmation while ticketing.

Command set for terminal user:

```
SI9«
A123.A9999A07.B..9A11 NOT SIGNED OUT <- response
W/C35IT‡ON«
TICKET CAT 35 IT/BT PQ FARE ALLOWED  <- response
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what is called 'mask handling'. You'll need to send the request as if you were working on a native Sabre mask. 
It should look something like the following:

```
<HostCommand><![CDATA[CO<Y>]]></HostCommand>
```

The Host command needs to be enclosed in a CDATA block in order for the service to not consider the "<" and ">" as part of the XML.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can you explain, what is "CO" in the brackets mean? Is it some special prefix?

Comment: Unfortunately I could not send any vulnerable symbols in CDATA. It is always screened while serializing into SOAP envelope in Java.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate a mask response, try this:

```
<HostCommand>CO&lt;Y&gt;</HostCommand>
```

...and be sure your XML construction software does not automatically convert those embedded codes before and after the "Y" into angled brackets.
The CO is the action code that tells native Sabre that this is a mask response to the mask prompt UNABLE TO TICKET STORED FARE - NEGOTIATED FARE STORED...